# What's the best way to send user-inputted text via AJAX to Google App Engine?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm developing in Google App Engine (python sdk) and I want to use jQuery to send an Ajax request to store an answer to a question.

What is the best way to send this data to the server?  Currently I have:

```
function storeItem(question_id) {
        var answerInputControl = ".input_answer_"+question_id;
        var answer_text = $(answerInputControl).text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "store_answer.html",
            data: "question="+question_id,
            success: function(responseText){
                alert("Retrieved: " + responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

This takes a question Id and provides it to the server via the query string.  But on the server-side, I'm unable to access the content of the answer control which I want to store.  Without Ajax, I'm able to perform this operation with the following:

```
class StoreAnswers(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    question_id = self.request.get("question_id")
    answer_text = self.request.get("input_answer" + question_id)
```

But when doing this call through Ajax, my `answer_text` is empty.

- Do I need to send the contents of this control as part of the data with the Ajax request?
- Do I add the control itself to the query string?  Its contents?  Does it matter that the content might be a few hundred characters long?  Is this the most-recommended practice?
- If sending it as a query string, what's the best way to escape the content so that a malicious user doesn't harm the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` in your `ajax` call must include all the data you want to send -- posting a few hundred characters is absolutely no problem and it's most definitely the recommended approach.

Do *not* use a `GET` in lieu of `POST` -- *that* (which I suspect is what you mean by "send as a query string") would only buy you trouble of all sorts, and is a violation of the semantics of `GET` (which should be limited to "read-only" queries, ones with no side effects).

Comment: I mentioned a query string because I thought this line in the ajax call "data: "question="+question_id" was building a query string, but I guess I was wrong in this.  What's a good way to escape the content before sending it through the ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is incorrectly formatted:

```
data: {
    question_id: question_id,
    input_answer: $(answerInputControl).text()
}
```

Comment: The ajax request in the example isn't sending over the answerInputControl's text.  Part of the question was if I had to, or if I could just access the controls from python (self.request.get('input_answer_questionID')), which works without ajax.  Thanks for giving a better way of sending the data though.